# Failing to generate the grammar

Tags: parsing, grammar

I have to check the syntax for a simple boolean expression such as 
(X = 100 and Y < 100), I wrote the grammar and tried to check if this was correct so I am using this online tool http://smlweb.cpsc.ucalgary.ca/start.html. it is saying the grammar is wrong.

can someone point out the issue here ? thanks in advance.

```
boolean       -> bool_term | boolean OR bool_term  
bool_term     -> bool_factor | bool_term AND bool_factor
bool_factor   -> bool_primary | NOT bool_primary
bool_primary  -> predicate | ( boolean )  
predicate     -> expr comp_op expr 
expr          -> string | number.
comp_op       -> = |  >
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! If my answer works for you, consider marking it as accepted. If it doesn't, comment on it.

Answer (score 1):

It is mostly about the stupid syntax of the service. For example, characters `=` and `>` are unsupported and there is no way to escape them.

This grammar works:

```
BOOLEAN       -> BOOLTERM | BOOLEAN or BOOLTERM  .
BOOLTERM      -> BOOLFACTOR | BOOLTERM and BOOLFACTOR .
BOOLFACTOR    -> BOOLPRIMARY | not BOOLPRIMARY .
BOOLPRIMARY   -> PREDICATE | ( BOOLEAN )  .
PREDICATE     -> EXPR COMPOP EXPR .
EXPR          -> string | number .
COMPOP        -> eq | gt .
```